# use an attribute outside from forkJoin

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the list `cardsbackground` that contains the name of images, to get the images i have an api that has as parameters certificate number and image name

I want to dislay the images that matches the names that are in the list `cardsbackground`

The problem is that `forkJoin` returns the list of images and i want to display for each image its name

When i want to display the name inside the `subscribe`, it displays nothing

```
forkJoin(
    this.cardsBackground.map(
        (name, index) => this.cardBackgroundService.getImage(certificateNumber, name)
    )
).subscribe(
    data => data.forEach(element => console.log(name + " - " + element))
);
```

Comment: Do you have write the API?Because if you write the api you can return for every image the name field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the `name` variable inside the scope of your `map` function, which makes it unaccessable inside the subscription scope.

An easy way would be to pipe the service call and return a new object with both the name and the result to be accessed later.

```
forkJoin(
    this.cardsBackground.map(
      (name, index) => this.cardBackgroundService.getImage(certificateNumber, name).pipe(
        map(image => ({
          name: name,
          image: image
        }))
      )
    )
).subscribe(data => data.forEach(element => console.log(element.name + " - " + element)));
```

Comment: the data of subscribe return undefined

Comment: I forgot a parenthesis wrapping around the object, should work now.